# MVC restrict access based on IP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ip-restrictions

I want to restrict access to my MVC project to a predetermined set of IP addresses. It should be quick and easy to add or remove IP addresses, possibly through an admin-interface on the webpage.

Which way would be best to implement this? Do i have to set the restriction in the web.config?

Answer (score 2):

You can set this in IIS, no need to do this specifically in ASP.NET MVC.

See [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733090%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on a complete how to do this.

If you do want to do this in MVC on a fine grained way for specific actions for example, you can create an own [`FilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterattribute.aspx#inheritanceContinued) to determine if the ip address for that action is authorized.